# Does locally compact plus pseudocompact imply paracompact?

Tags: gn.general-topology, paracompactness, compactifications

This one is probably simple, but I don't see it yet.

Is a locally compact, pseudocompact Hausdorff space necessarily paracompact?

Comment: If you sometimes have questions like this, get a copy of the book COUNTEREXAMPLES IN TOPOLOGY by Steen and Seebach.  There are tables in the back to look up examples with various combinations of properties.

Comment: @AustinMohr's link referenced [above](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/249026) seems now to have moved to [π-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/).

Comment: Specifically to this question: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/?q=Locally+Compact%2BPseudocompact%2B%24T_2%24%2B%7EParacompact

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any pseudocompact paracompact Hausdorff space is compact. So $\omega_1$ with the order topology is a counterexample to your question since it is locally compact, pseudocompact (any real valued continuous function is eventually constant) and not compact.

Answer (score 6):

The [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29) is one of the standard examples of a space that is not paracompact. It is however Hausdorff, locally compact, and pseudocompact because maps from it to $\mathbb R$ are eventually constant.

Comment: Thanks. This seem correct, but the example below $\omega_1$ is a bit simpler.